# What is 'Kabir Sagar'?

Tags: philosophy, saint

I read some part of ' Kabir Sagar'. It is a book on Saint Kabir which concerns with philosophical knowledge (or so I think). But I don't understand what it talks about to begin with. 
Will anyone shed some light on what the book is about ? It is really confusing. It is difficult to understand what it talks about.

Comment: If you could link the book, then users may get an idea which you are talking about. There is a compilation by Yogananda. Is that the one?